# Add parent site columnLink to a contentType

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have a subsite where I created a contentType. I want to a add columnLink from the parent site using:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/contentTypes/{contentType-id}/columnLinks
```

Adding current site columns works as expected, however when adding columnLink from parent site, fails with such response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The referenced column does not exist",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...,
            "date": "2018-07-31T11:05:34"
        }
    }
}
```

The body that was sent:

```
{ 
  "name": "Detail" 
}
```

The endpoint works correctly for both id and name in request body. (For current site columnLinks)

Answer (score 0):

According to your questions, I suppose you want to add a columnLink from parent site.

Based on my test, If we want to add a column to a contentType, we can get the column first by this API:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/columns`. This step is to ensure that the column exists. The part of response will be like this:

```
{
     "name": "{column Name}",
     "id": "{column Id}"
}
```

Then we add site columnLink to a contentType, we can use this column Name like this:

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/contentTypes/{contentType-id}/columnLinks`

The body like this:

```
{
    "name":"{column Name}"
}
```

or

```
{
    "id": "{column Id}"
}
```

Comment: Can you do that with a columnLink from a parent site?

Comment: Yes, I did this in the root site to add a columnLink

Comment: What I mean is to have a subsite and have a content type created there and than add columnLink from a parent site(the column belongs to a parent site). Is this the case you did?

Comment: It is like an inheritance relationship. The ContentType of the child site can access the ContentType of the parent site, but the parent site cannot access the ContentType of the child site.

Comment: The thing is that I have a column in parent site that is doesn't relative to any content type. In web ui I can easily  add it to a content type from a subsite.

Comment: Yes, we can add a column from the parent site in a subsite. However, the reverse is not possible.

Comment: In content type case, can you add parent site column to it?

Comment: No, we can't add a subsite' s column to a parent site content type

Comment: I want to add parent site column to a subsite content type

Comment: Yes, this case can be supported

Comment: Did you try this case?

Comment: Yes, as I posted comment below

Comment: Are you sure that you added columnLink from a parent site?

Comment: Have you encountered any problems during the operation?

Comment: Yes, I have the response: `{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The referenced column does not exist",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": ,
            "date": "2018-08-27T07:50:04"
        }
    }
} `for each columnLink from a parent site.